# returning multiple column and sum using linq expression

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I need to return two fields using a lambda expression. The first one is the sum of the amount field and the second one is CurrentFinancial year. Below is the code that I have written, how do I include CurrentFinancialYear?

```
var amount = dealingContext.vw_GetContribution
                           .Where(o => o.ContactID == contactId)
                           .Sum(o => o.Amount);
return new Contribution { Amount = amount ?? 0, CurrentFinancialYear =  };
```

Comment: Where is `CurrentFinancialYear` coming from? Database? A calculation based on a set formula?

Comment: Where do you retrieve the financial year? Is it located inside your vw_GetContribution object?

Comment: What do you want to return as `CurrentFinancialYear`? `DateTime.Now.Year`?

Comment: its coming from the database. The view contains a function currentfinancial year which returns as column and part of the views resultset.For example it returns a value 2015/16

Comment: If I understand correctly, you need to look into the GroupBy method and group by the year, then you can get the sum for each year. But that doesn't fit with your return value.

Comment: This is my sql and i want linq representation for this

Comment: select CurrentFinancialYear,sum(Amount) as Amount from vw_GetSippContribution
where CONTACTid = 2106525
group by CurrentFinancialYear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grouping by Year should do the trick:

```
            from entry in ledger.Entries
            where entry.ContactID == contactId
            && entry.Time.Year == currentFinancialYear
            group entry by entry.Time.Year
            into g
            select new Contribution () 
            {
                Amount = g.ToList ().Sum (e => e.Amount),
                CurrentFinancialYear = g.Key
            };
```

UPDATE - just return the first/default result...

```
            (from entry in ledger.Entries
            where entry.ContactID == contactId
            && entry.Time.Year == currentFinancialYear
            group entry by entry.Time.Year
            into g
            select new Contribution () 
            {
                Amount = g.ToList ().Sum (e => e.Amount),
                CurrentFinancialYear = g.Key
            }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Hi I need to return it as an object. The logic is written inside this method public SippContribution GetSippContribution(int contactId)
  {
   using (var dealingContext = new dbDealingContainer())
   {
    
    

   }
  }

Comment: I need to return for example return new Contribution { Amount = amount ?? 0, CurrentFinancialYear =  };

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
var amount = dealingContext.vw_GetContribution
            .Where(o => o.ContactID == contactId)
            .GroupBy(o=> new { o.CurrentFinancialYear, o.Amount})
            .Select(group =>
                   new { 
                      year= group.Key.CurrentFinancialYear, 
                      sum= group.Sum(x=>x.Amount) 
                       });
```

Comment: Hi I need to return it as an object. The logic is written inside this method public SippContribution GetSippContribution(int contactId) { using (var dealingContext = new dbDealingContainer()) { } }

Comment: I need to return for example return new Contribution { Amount = amount ?? 0, CurrentFinancialYear = }

Answer (score 0):

First of all use a simple select

```
var contribution = dealingContext.vw_GetContribution
                              .Where(o => o.ContactID == contactId).ToList();
```

It will give you a list of type `vw_GetContribution`

Then use `groupby` on this list as

```
var groupedContribution = contribution.GroupBy(b => b.CurrentFinancialYear).ToList();
```

Now you can iterate through or use this list as

```
foreach(var obj in groupedContribution.SelectMany(result => result).ToList())
{
      var amount = obj.Amount;
      var Year = obj.CurrentFinancialYear;
}
```

---

OR
In single line, you can do all the above as

```
var contList = context.vw_GetContribution
                           .Select(a => new { a.Amount, a.CurrentFinancialYear })
                           .GroupBy(b => b.CurrentFinancialYear)
                           .SelectMany(result => result).ToList();
```

I hope this will solve your problem.